# Getting the number of Ethereum related tweets (per hour)

Tags: python, twitter, ethereum, tweets

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the number of tweets per hour that has the word "Ethereum" in them in the last month.
Does anybody have an idea of how can I do that ?

Comment: use twitter API and make a GET request to search tweets and put word 'Ethereum' and time in request parameters. not sure if twitter api has a response size limit.... a month is a lot of data

Comment: I would start with Google - to find informations, tutorials, modules.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of code out there on how to scrape tweets, you can use the twitter API too, then just search every tweet for the word 'Ethereum' in it.

Not going to spoon feed you the exact solution but google.

1. How to scrape tweets using python?
2. How to find a word in a string in python.